# Redirect to another page fails on login verification

Tags: php, html, mysql

The following code redirects to a blank page instead to a `.php` file.

**What have I tried?**

I try to use the `header()` function to redirect the user to another `.php` file, if the user exists in the `MYSQL` database, and the password is equal to the one in the `MYSQL` database.

**What is my current code?**

```
<?php

session_start();
$verbindung = mysql_connect( "localhost", "******" , "*****" ); mysql_select_db( "m7_studios_de" );

$username = $_POST["username"];
$passwort = $_POST["password"];

$ergebnis = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($ergebnis))
    if($row->password == $passwort){
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
        header("Location: http://www.m7-studios.de/overview.php");
        exit;
    }
    else{
        header( "Location: http://www.m7-studios.de/");
        exit;
    }

?>
```

Comment: 1) Don't user LIKE in ur query. It should be like where username=$username AND password=$password
2) If row count is 1 (one row found) login is successfull
3) Password should be hashed
4) There are some syntax errors
5) cant echo after (or before) redirect (header(""))

Comment: Your scripts contain syntax error, fix first those then check!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this should work

- Username must be unique + case sensitive
- Password should be hashed
- Code redirects to the login page with GET error=loginfailed if login fails

---

```
<?php
    $verbindung = mysql_connect( "localhost", "******" , "*****" ); 
    mysql_select_db( "m7_studios_de" );
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $passwort = $_POST["password"];
    $abfrage = "SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($abfrage);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1) {
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
        header("Location: http://foo.com/logged_in.php");
        die();
    } else {
        header("Location: http://foo.com/index?error=loginfailed");
        die();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Don't output any whitespace before your header() call or it won't work.  You are outputting whitespace between the first and second blocks of php

2) Don't mix mysql and mysqli functions - you are using `mysqli_fetch_object`.  In fact don't use mysql functions at all, they are deprecated

3) Use parameterised queries to protect yourself against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're mixing `mysql_` (in your connection) with `mysqli_`(fetching rows). You need to use one or the other throughout. I'd suggest `mysqli_` since `mysql_` is deprecated.